# My SQL DELETE query works in PMA but not in my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

My name is HiCt, new to SOF.

For my school project I need to create a website with some PHP scripts combined with SQL in it. My page is currently showing correctly my SQL table on a PHP website.

Now I created a remove action to remove rows directly from the page, i tested it in Phpmyadmin and it works but it doesnt on my website.

Can anyone see why it isn't working? I noticed that it creates a URL where it trys to delete the $naam and not the $id like he is supposed to.

'

```
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "winkel");
        error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); #Verberg meldingen van PHP
        #error_reporting(E_ALL);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met de database!";
            exit();
        }

        if($_GET['action']=="remove")
        {;
        $sqli = "DELETE FROM klanten WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." ";

        echo ($conn->query($sqli) === true) ? "De klant is verwijderd." : "De klant kon niet worden verwijderd.";
        }

        $sqli = "SELECT * FROM `klanten`";

        if ($stmti = $conn->prepare($sqli)) {
            if (!$stmti->execute()) {
                echo "cant exec: <br> " . $stmti->error;
                exit();
            } else {
                $stmti->bind_result($id, $naam, $adres, $woonplaats, $contactpersoon, $telefoonnummer, $emailadres, $betalingsachterstand);
                $stmti->store_result(); 

                while($stmti->fetch()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $id . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $naam . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $adres . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $woonplaats . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $contactpersoon . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $telefoonnummer . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $emailadres . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $betalingsachterstand . "</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='klantbewerken.php?id=".$naam."&action=edit'>Bewerken</a></td>"; #Op een of andere manier melding bewerken
                    echo "<td><a href='klanten.php?id=".$id."&action=remove'>Verwijderen</a></td>"; # Verwijder een row uit de DB
                    echo "</tr>";
                }

            }
        } else {
            echo "can't prepare: <br> " . $stmti->error;
            exit();
        }
        ?>'
```

Comment: $sqli = "DELETE FROM klanten WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." "; SQL injection possible here

Comment: remove semicolon here if($_GET['action']=="remove")
        {;

Comment: Thx for your comment JYoTHl, to bad it didn't work :(. Please see my respone to Nages Katke for more info.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thnx! It's for private use but still thank you :)

Comment: may be $_GET['id'] is empty @HiCt

Comment: Doesnt it pickup the ID through the URL? (Sorry im a noob PHPer like u see lol) What should be between the ['ID'] brackets? Something like [$id] ?

Comment: @HiCt your html?

Comment: Do you want the HTML? Full page can be found here: https://pastebin.com/9UTjZy9n

Comment: Not all, just the one where you go get the id. And another question, how are you submitting the html values ​​to php? AJAX or simple form post.

Comment: @JoseMarques through a URL, see the pastebin link I posted for the whole webpage.

Comment: @HiCt From what I read, you are receiving the correct id.

Comment: @JoseMarques Yes, but for some reason ".$_GET['id']." "; that part isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? I can see clearly a syntax error in your code.

```
 if($_GET['action']=="remove")
    {;
    $sqli = "DELETE FROM klanten WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." ";

    echo ($conn->query($sqli) === true) ? "De klant is verwijderd." : "De klant kon niet worden verwijderd.";
    }
```

Remove ; after { in above code

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It doesn't give an error, it just says the customer couldnt be removed (De klant kon niet worden verwijderd).

When I hover above the Remove button it gives this url: http://localhost/winkel/aftersales/klanten.php?id=Test&action=remove

id=Test isnt going right, Test is the name not the ID, the ID is a INT. I think the fault is somewhere there but I cant find out how to fix it.

Comment: @Nagesh Katke a semicon is allowed after brackets it wont generate a error see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6da60fd147d3312257b8494bf4f0b53026dd8ae

Comment: Ah ok! I just fixed the weird URL problem, my order in columns was wrong in SQL, it gives the right URL now but still it doesnt remove my rows.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

```
echo "<td><a href='klanten.php?id=".$id."&action=remove'>Verwijderen</a></td>"; # Verwijder een row uit de DB     - had a error.
```

It had to be klantid= instead of id= etc.

Thanks a lot for the help everyone.